# Change theme from Admin View Silverstripe

Tags: themes, silverstripe

I'm using Silverstripe 4.x version and I'm quite new to SilverStripe. In my application I want to have a new theme created. I created the new theme folder structure and a Page.ss file also. According to the guides that I watched from admin panel we should have an option to change the theme. But I don't get any option in admin settings view to change the theme. I only get the following. What I'm missing here.

[image: current view]

Answer (score 1):

This may have been removed from SilverStripe4. It was present in SS3.

To change the theme, you can edit your **mysite/_config/theme.yml** file.

Comment: Might be worth adding a little config snippet as an example =)